# Oque faz a função de %% e %any% no r?

Tags: r, operadores

Estive lendo a documentação do R e no documento `Arithmetic{base}`, `Arithmetic Operators` me deparei com o `%%` que diz ter a função mod, que presumi que fosse a função modulo, mas quando executei me pareceu com a função `rep()`, então não entendi a logica. Esbarrei com `%<%` ou `%<%` que parecia receber uma função e executa-las de forma diferente do normal, isto é, dentro do `()`.

Comment: A não ser que tu tenha carregado algum pacote extra que tenha deixado a função `%%` masked, ela é a função módulo. Note que o resultado de `17 %% 3` é 2, pois `17 = 3*5 + 2`. Ou seja, 2 é o resto da divisão inteira entre 17 e 3. O teu computador está reportando algo diferente? Quanto à função `%<%` eu não posso te ajudar, pois só conheço `%>%`, também chamada de _pipe_.

Comment: Entendi, o problema era o meu conceito de modulo, como sendo valor absoluto.<br\> Devo ter escrito errado ````%>%````.

Comment: Agora há dois `%<%` seguidos no texto e um `%any%` no título. O que é esse `%any%`? Em que pacote pode ser encontrado? `sos::findFn('%any%') não encontra essa função.

Comment: Eu acredito que o AP deseja saber qual o significado da função `%>%` (pipe), Rui. Ao menos foi pensando nisso que escrevi a minha resposta.

Comment: Estranho... Eu tinha certeza de ter visto referencia com ```%any%``` ou ```%whatever%```, no sentido de qualquer coisa dentro do ```% %```, mas agora não estou achando as referencias disso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função `%%` é a função módulo, no sentido de aritmética modular. Note que o resultado de `17 %% 3` é `2`, pois `17 = 3*5 + 2`. Além disso, veja que o resultado de `17 %/% 3` é 5, complementando o resultado de `%%`. Portanto, as funções `%%` e `%/%` servem para realizar a divisão inteira dentro do R.

A função `%>%`, também chamada de *pipe*, serve para encadear comandos. Talvez o pacote que melhor faça isso é o `dplyr`. Imagine que eu queira pegar o conjunto de dados `iris` e realizar algumas operações nele:

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Vamos supor que eu queira selecionar apenas colunas `Petal.Length` e `Petal.Width`, cujo `Sepal.Length` seja maior do que 5, mas apenas da espécies setosa. Eu posso fazer isso no R assim:

```
subset(iris[iris$Sepal.Length > 5, c(3, 4, 5)], Species=="setosa")
```

Note como a sintaxe é complicada. Embora façam o trabalho direito, as funções `subset` e as procuras por índices pelo `R` não são muito amigáveis. Veja como tudo fica mais fácil com o *pipe*:

```
iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length > 5) %>%
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
  select(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species)
```

Com o *pipe* eu vou encadeando comandos. Eu pego o resultado do conjunto `iris` e passo para a filtragem de acordo com o `Sepal.Length > 5`; em seguida, pego este resultado e passo para a filtragem `Species == "setosa"`; e, por fim, seleciono apenas as colunas que me interessam.

É muito mais limpo para escrever os códigos e muito mais fácil de ler depois, seja o teu próprio código escrito no passado, seja o código de outra pessoa.

**Curiosidade:** a função `%>%` surgiu em um pacote chamado `magrittr`, que anteriormente era chamado de `plumbr`. O pacote tem teste nome em homenagem à René Magritte, pintor belga que produziu a obra abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

"Isto não é um cachimbo"

O comando pipe surgiu numa outra linguagem de programação chamada F#. Quando veio para o R, o autor do pacote `plumbr` decidiu fazer um grande trocadilho, juntando o conceito de pipe (cano, em inglês) com pipe (cachimbo, em francês) e homenagear assim um pintor famoso. [Fonte com mais detalhes desta história](http://adolfoalvarez.cl/plumbers-chains-and-famous-painters-the-history-of-the-pipe-operator-in-r/).